# Django Admin display foreign key value

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to display the foreign key value itself in the Django Admin Panel.

```
admins.py:
class CateogoriesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

list_display = ('category_name',)

class CateogoriesItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

list_display = ('category_name', 'item_name', 'item_description',)


Models.py:
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class CategoryItems(models.Model):
    category_name = = models.ForeignKey(Categories, related_name='categoriesfk', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

With the above, I just get Categories Object (1) as value, I want to display the actual value in the Django admin panel not object (1), e.g. if there is a category called "Bicycle", it should display Bicycle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to tell django what to show when representing object category as string. for example

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
```